# Dropdownlist in MVC using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using entity framework in mvc3. I have a table in which two entries are coming from an another table in the shape of drop down list. Like emp_no and emp_name.
Now i want that when i select Emp_no from the first drop down list,the corresponding emp_name 
will be selected automatically.

Is this possible ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why not?, hope when you are binding, you are binding name as text and id as value, then according to the change event from first ddl, you can change the selected item of second. Hope you got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Details:** It is possible and the task will be much more easier if the emp_no is the value in the emp_name drop down list. If that is the case then the following is the solution using JQuery.

**Solution:**

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
         $('#ddlEmployeeNumbers').change(function ()            
          {
            var employeeNum = $('#ddlEmployeeNumbers').val();
            $('#ddlEmployeeName').val(employeeNum);
          });
    });
</script>
```

**Alternative:** If you don't have the emp_no as the value in the emp_name drop down then you should do an ajax call for more information go to this website [AJAX-calls-with-jQuery-in-ASP.NET-MVC](http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/AJAX-calls-with-jQuery-in-ASP.NET-MVC)